# How to Bitcoin Core daemon start automatically each time your reboot your computer.?

Tags: bitcoind, ubuntu

In the official document of [bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#other-linux-distributions), they ask to use an init script instead of cron job, see the init scripts directory in Bitcoin Core’s source tree.

But the link is not working
[Bitcoin Core’s source tree](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/0.13/contrib/init)

Cron Job option

> @reboot bitcoind -daemon

I wanted to know the init script to restart a daemon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The init scripts can be found here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/contrib/init.

Comment: Can you please explain the working  of this command to start bitcoin daemon